# How to share a trained model of im2txt (Show and Tell) in Tensorflow?

Tags: model, tensorflow

I am interested in sharing a trained model of Show and telling to the community. I have trained the model available in [tensorflow/models repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models).
I am not sure which files I should be sharing. I think the files that are to be shared are:

model.ckpt-NUMBER.meta (where NUMBER is a 6 digit number)
graph.pbtxt
word_counts.txt (Since different versions of the tokenizer can yield different outputs)

It would be great if someone could tell me what all resources I should be sharing.

Answer (score 0):

The latest checkpoint (highest version number), graph, and word_counts.txt files should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

One has to share the following files:

model.ckpt-???????.index

model.ckpt-???????.data-00000-of-00001

word_counts.txt

where ??????? represents how many iterations are done. In other words, the highest number found.

Here is the trained model in case someone is interested: [Pretrained-Show-and-Tell-model](https://github.com/KranthiGV/Pretrained-Show-and-Tell-model)